# Navigate to another view using action field

Tags: grails

I have 3 View classes. They are `Person, Animal and Building` (These are 3 folders, and in each folder there's a view called `show.gsp`). From the Person view i want to navigate to the `Animal` view. How can i do it from the code below.

```
<td><g:link action="show" id="${rx.id}">${fieldValue(bean: rx, field: "name")}</g:link></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify target controller also:

```
<g:link controller="animal" action="show" id="${rx.id}">${fieldValue(bean: rx, field: "name")}</g:link>
```